Can't add SMB printer
When I try to install a printer that's shared via Windows, I can't add that printer, as the credentials are apparently wrong.

First, make sure the smbclient and python3-smbc packages are installed:
sudo apt install smbclient python3-smbc
A few other things I had to do were: Use the IP address of the computer, since the Windows Internet Name Service apparently didn't work. Also, the "test credentials" thing doesn't work either - it says my credentials are wrong despite me being able to print. So, in case you know your credentials are correct, don't trust the "Verify" button.

